# react native Bottom Sheet navigation header too tall

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Im using the [@gorhom/bottom-sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) library for the bottom sheet, I am using react native navigation stack inside the sheet, this is taken from the [bottom sheet navigation example](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/blob/cb58a8aaf90fcd0f7b497b6d1d05db60c7088fde/example/bare/src/screens/integrations/NavigatorExample.tsx). The header is way taller than it should be. How could i solve this problem without changing the structure and not setting a header hight in px? Thanks.

```
const CoolScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>CoolScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const SheetNavigator = ({ navigationRef }) => {
  const screenOptions = useMemo(
    () => ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#f4511e",
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions} headerMode="screen">
        <Stack.Screen name="FlatList Screen" component={CoolScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

<BottomSheet
   ref={bottomSheetRef}
   index={0}
   snapPoints={snapPoints}
   enablePanDownToClose={true}
>
  <SheetNavigator navigationRef={navigationRef} />
</BottomSheet>
```

[image]

I tried replacing the navigation stack and the bottom sheet components, however that did not help.